# QGIS DXF export creating hatches with no area in AutoCAD

Tags: qgis, dxf, autocad

I am having some issues with a DXF export from QGIS. When i open the DXF file in AutoCAD, the hatches that are generating to represent the polygons in QGIS are all generating without areas.

[image: Example hatch selected in AutoCAD]

Is there a better way to transfer the vector polygon layer from QGIS into AutoCAD that would allow AutoCAD to see these as properly generated hatches and thus calculate an area for them?

If I generate a boundary for the hatch and reassign it to that newly generated boundary then the hatch works as expected and AutoCAD can calculate it's area.
[image]

Comment: fyi QGIS calculates the ellipsoisal area, and AutocCAD calculates the planimetric area https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/autocad-forum/different-areas-in-autocad-and-qgis/td-p/8895051 do you have the area calculated before exporting in QGIS?

Comment: Hi Mapperz, good to know, thank you. So for more context what I am doing is creating to seperate plans in AutoCAD of a site (at which point I can calculate areas). I am then saving these as dxf files and importing them into QGIS to UNION them to calculate the overlaps and then returning the product to AutoCAD to create the final map with key as QGIS is somewhat clunky in it's layout generation.

Comment: DXF files are created in 2004 format and I think their hatches doesn't have the boundary geometry attached. But maybe you can export the polygons as closed polylines instead, setting the proper configuration option.